# Which part of 2001 takes place in 2001?

Tags: 2001-a-space-odyssey

The film *2001: A Space Odyssey* is divided into several sections. The first, "The Dawn of Man", takes place in the distant past. This is followed by a sequence in which Heywood Floyd visits the monolith on the moon, and then after that we have the mission to Jupiter, which takes place 18 months later, according to a title card that appears on screen.

Presumably, either the second or third part of the film takes place in the year 2001. But which is it? Does Floyd visit Tycho in 1999 or so, with Bowman and co heading to Jupiter in 2001, or is the monolith discovered in 2001 with the Jupiter mission taking place a year or so later?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the monolith is detected and uncovered in 2001, with *Discovery* leaving for Jupiter the next year (2002).

Comment: no reference to the date in the book fwiw

Comment: The text introduction to the sequel, 2010, says that the monolith was discovered in 1999. However, it also says it was found in the Sea of Tranquillity, not Tycho crater, so that can be safely ignored.

Comment: @GordonD I agree with you that 2010 can be ignored as far as 2001 canon goes, but that's useful all the same - I've posted an answer with that information but won't accept it. (If you'd rather get the points feel free to post your own answer and I'll delete mine.)

Comment: @N.Virgo No, leave things as they are; your answer goes into more detail than my comment

Answer (score 28):

The [early](https://imsdb.com/scripts/2001-A-Space-Odyssey.html) [scripts](http://www.archiviokubrick.it/opere/film/2001/script/2001-originalscript.pdf) include a title card preceding Floyd's arrival at the space station that establish the date as 2001.  They also include the date of the discovery of TMA-1 in Floyd's secret briefing that Bowman hears after he disconnects HAL:

> Thirteen months before the launch date of your Saturn mission, on April 12th, 2001, the first evidence for intelligent life outside the Earth was discovered.

Obviously a great deal was changed in the final movie; it was 18 months before, not 13, the date and destination were omitted, and the depth of TMA-1 was changed from "15 metres" to "40 feet."  (Not to mention the whole changing the destination from Saturn to Jupiter.)

There are no current dates at all given in the book (only historical dates, like the moonbase founded in 1994, and HAL's activation in 1997), and I didn't find any current dates in the released movie either.

That said, it's fairly clear in the original scripts that "2001" referred to the year that TMA-1 was discovered.

Comment: Interesting choice changing the units to feet - I get that it was for a US audience (even though NASA generally uses metric), but if they were gonna change it, 15 metres is much closer to *50* feet (~49.2126) than 40.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman The standardization on SI units is more recent. My first satellite ops experience was SAS-3 in 1975, where slugs and feet were the units used for mass properties, while the magtorquer moments, used to point that mass where we wanted to look, were in CGS electromagnetic units, pole-cm!

Comment: @DarrelHoffman: And "fifty feet" sounds nicer too.

Comment: Another one of those changes: "your Saturn mission" became Jupiter

Comment: @TomGoodfellow  D'oh!  How on Earth did I miss that?

Answer (score 22):

As noted in a comment by GordonD, if one accepts the sequel *2010: The Year we Make Contact* as canon, then the Heywood Floyd sequence takes place in 1999 and the Poole and Bowman sequence takes place in 2001. This is evidenced by the on-screen text in the intro to *2010*:

[image]

[image]

(I am not sure why that text says the monolith was discovered in the Sea of Tranquility, given that it was Tycho crater in the original and the same text later on says the monolith was called the "Tycho monolith".)

It's also mentioned later in the movie (*2010*) that HAL's secret orders were dated January 30, 2001, which is consistent with this timeline.

So in the sequel it's made unambiguous, but since *2010* is quite a different movie than *2001* and wasn't made by Kubrick I'm not sure I accept it as canon.

Comment: Keep in mind that Arthur C. Clarke wrote pretty much all the relevant material: the original short story "The Sentinel" in 1948, the novel *2001* (which preceded his screenplay for the movie at Kubrick's suggestion), and the novel *2010* on which the sequel movie was based. While the original movie and novel had their differences (the novel use a moon of Saturn as the destination), there is a foreword in *2010* discussing various decisions and changes made while writing *2010* (including the decision to keep Jupiter as the destination). (1/2)

Comment: I don't recall timeline details, but it would be worth checking the source novel *2010* to see what it says. (2/2)

Comment: As for Sea of Tranquility vs. Tycho Crater - it's obviously dumbed down because audiences of the time wouldn't necessarily have heard of the Tycho Crater, but *everyone* knew about the Sea of Tranquility because of Apollo 11.  (Yes, that wouldn't happen for another year, but the plans were widely publicized beforehand.)

Comment: Maybe Tranquility is where the moonbase was, from which the expedition was sent to Tycho.

Comment: @chepner: Are you sure that he wrote the novel *before* writing the screenplay? The copy of the novel that I read has an introduction by Clarke, and I could swear that he mentions in it that parts of the book were influenced by seeing parts of the movie.

Comment: The novel was published *after* the movie was released, but was written first to provide a more fleshed-out version on which the screenplay could be based. I am summarizing (too briefly and perhaps inaccurately) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthur_C._Clarke#2001:_A_Space_Odyssey.

Comment: I haven't read either book in a good 25 years or more. My main memory is the foreword to 2010 talking about why the movie and book differ in which planet's moon had the obelisk, and why the book *2010* kept the movie's use of Jupiter. (Something along the line of Jupiter being a better idea, and the original voyage to Saturn was kept for the book instead of editing to match the finished movie. I gather the book was already delayed long past its original target publication, which would have been before the movie was released.)

Comment: @chepner The decision for using Jupiter in the films was mostly due to concerns about creating Saturn's ring system (which we knew precious little before Voyager). Of course, we also now know that there is a smaller, less distinct and sparser ring system around Jupiter.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman the intro text is from the movie 2010, which was made in 1984, not from 2001 (1969). I would say Tranquility vs. Tycho must just be a mistake on the part of whoever wrote that text. (The intro text doesn't appear in the script, so it was probably added at some point after filming.)

Comment: @chepner I guess the main thing for me is that Kubrick preferred a more mysterious approach than Clarke. Some things that are made explicit in Clarke's version are left deliberately unresolved in Kubrick's, so I tend to treat them as different, but related, works. There's also the issue that the continuity isn't perfect between Clarke's novels - he characterises them as taking place in parallel universes to each other rather than being direct sequels, so even in the novels 2010 canon is different from 2001 canon.

Comment: @Barmar No, the Moonbase was in Clavius crater, which is much closer to Tycho than the Sea of Tranquillity. I agree with Darrell Goffman that the on-screen text said that because people would have heard of it.

Comment: I cannot believe I never noticed that said Sea of Tranquilty and Tycho!

Answer (score 3):

Floyd's trip to the moon, and his visit to TMA-1, take place in late February 2001. During the moon bus flight, Floyd reviews some documents that have visible date stamps. This TMA-1 document has date stamp 021201, presumably February 12, 2001:

[image: Screenshot from "2001: A Space Odyssey" depicting a TMA-1 document]

Floyd visits TMA-1 just a short time later, which makes the date mid to late February 2001.

Comment: There was a full moon February 8, 2001, thus TMA-1 had already been exposed to sunlight prior to Floyd's visit!

Comment: I'm not saying you're wrong, but pretty much anywhere other than the US that would be December 1, 2002.  (Failing that, December 2, 2001.)

Comment: Agreed, but this is a US base and US spacecraft. And the filming is taking place in 1966! I think it's reasonable to assume an old-style US date format.